# Same colors everywhere : terminal, tty, tmux

Tags: colorscheme

## My goal

I'm using Neovim under Linux (Arch Linux), but I think it would be just the same with original vim.

I'd like to be able to use nvim with the same colors in a virtual console (tty1, tty2...) without X, and in my terminal emulator (rxvt-unicode) under X (with tmux or not).

## What I've done already

I've chosen a theme in my `vimrc` file: `colorscheme peachpuff` (it seems to be the default one, anyway). I've chosen this theme on purpose since it's a 16 color theme.

I've reset the colors in my `.bashrc` to match the peachpuff theme colors :

```
if [ "$TERM" = "linux" ]; then
    echo -en "\e]P0343742" #black
    echo -en "\e]P1F5958B" #darkred
    echo -en "\e]P2B7E48C" #darkgreen
    echo -en "\e]P3FFFFB9" #brown
    echo -en "\e]P47EB6FF" #darkblue
    echo -en "\e]P5C5C8C6" #darkmagenta
    echo -en "\e]P6C2EFFF" #darkcyan
    echo -en "\e]P7DDDDDD" #lightgrey
    echo -en "\e]P8CCCCCC" #darkgrey
    echo -en "\e]P9FF8D80" #red
    echo -en "\e]PADBFFB3" #green
    echo -en "\e]PBFFBE64" #yellow
    echo -en "\e]PCA8CEEA" #blue
    echo -en "\e]PDE296FF" #magenta
    echo -en "\e]PE9CE9FF" #cyan
    echo -en "\e]PFEEEEEE" #white
    #clear #for background artifacting
fi
```

## What works

It mostly works: the colors are approximately the same in a virtual console as in my terminal emulator. Using `tmux` in both of them changes nothing: the colors remain the same. So far, so good!

## What doesn't work

1. The colors are mostly the same (the blue is blue, the red is red, etc.), but in fact they are much more pale in the virtual console; to the point that it's sometimes hard to tell if a color (e.g. the blue one) is used or not, whereas there's no doubt in my terminal emulator. Why is that? Does it default to a near and more pale color, or is there another reason? And how can I avoid it?
2. The vim/nvim background in a terminal emulator is always black (`#000000`, which seems weird to me, since it's not defined anywhere in my colorscheme), whereas in a virtual console it matches the black color defined in the `.bashrc` (`echo -en "\e]P0343742" #black`, which seems more logical). How can I have them match together, without setting the black color to `#000000` (since it's used in the theme as a gray-ish color)? Another way to ask it would be: is there a way to set the virtual console background separately?

## Bonus question

3. Does anyone know of a 16 color scheme anywhere that would have a matching `.bashrc` theme, that would just work, and save me the pain to find all this by myself? I wonder why it is so hard to find this; I'm surprised no one seems to have done this before, since if it worked, I could live in a virtual console most of the time, without running X and a terminal emulator...

Comment: Fwiw, I use dracula for my terminal and vim themes, and a bit of similar colors for tmux.

Comment: The problem is not between using tmux or not ; it's between a tty and a terminal emulator ; I've noted that using tmux doesn't change anything.

Comment: You refer to terminal, tty and terminal emulator as three distinct things. Problem is these terms are used interchangeably or have multiple meanings. It would help if you more explicitly define the three things across which you're trying to sync colors.

Comment: You're right. I've tried to make it more clear : by `tty`, I meant the virtual console without X ; by `terminal emulator`, I meant `rxvt-unicode` launched after `startx`.

Comment: Welcome to Vi & Vim! For the future, please refrain from asking multiple questions in one. I actually have an answer for your question 2, but it's hard for me to post it as an answer since it doesn't cover 1 (or 3) and I don't really know about those...

Comment: See rxvt's configuration for colors: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rxvt-unicode#Colors you have the 16 numbered colors but you also have separate foreground and background (and cursor). I think `URxvt.foreground: rgb:34/37/42` in your `.Xresources` will configure that the way you want.

Comment: Those questions are linked together. There's only one problem : having the same colors using vim in the Linux console and in a terminal (hence the "bonus question"). I know about `.Xresources`. Your answer is a way to set the terminal background ; the question was about setting the Linux virtual console background.